# google recaptcha Warning: Illegal string offset 'success'

Tags: php, recaptcha

I'm trying to implement the google recaptcha for the first time and am running into this error: `Warning: Illegal string offset 'success'`

this is the code that needs to check if the recaptcha works out:

```
$response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=MYSECRETCODEHERE&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

if($response["success"] == false){   
     echo('spam');
}else{
    echo('not spam');
}
```

Comment: `file_get_contents` return `string`, but you access it as `array`.

Comment: prepare `$response` before using. To example, if response is `json`, use `json_decode`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks to @maximkou for giving the answer to my question, I had to change `response["success"] == false` to `response == false`